# I am writing change output program in C++. I am not getting the right result

Tags: c++

I am writing change output program in C++. I am not getting the right result...
In the output below, the result should be
1 Quarter and
1 Nickle.

Instead I am getting
1 Quarter and
4 Pennies

Is there anything I am missing here?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void calculateChange(double& x, double& y) {
    int change = (x - y) * 100;
    if (change < 0) {
        cout << "NOT ENOUGH FOR THE TRANSACTION!";
    }
    else {
        cout << "You will need....\n" << change / 5000 << " $50 bill(s), \n";
        change = change % 5000;
        cout << change / 2000 << " $20 bill(s), \n";
        change = change % 2000;
        cout << change / 1000 << " $10 bill(s), \n";
        change = change % 1000;
        cout << change / 500 << " $5 bill(s), \n";
        change = change % 500;
        cout << change / 100 << " $1 bill(s), \n";
        change = change % 100;
        cout << change / 25 << " Quarter(s), \n";
        change = change % 25;
        cout << change / 10 << " Dime(s), \n";
        change = change % 10;
        cout << change / 5 << " Nickle(s) and \n";
        change = change % 5;
        cout << change / 1 << " Penney.\n";
    }
 }

int main() {

    double moneyCharge, moneyGiven;
    int remainder;
    cout << "Enter the amount of the transaction $: ";
    cin >> moneyCharge;
    cout << "Enter the amount received $: ";
    cin >> moneyGiven;
    calculateChange(moneyGiven, moneyCharge);
    return 0;
}
```

RESULT OUTPUT

```
Enter the amount of the transaction $: 0.65
Enter the amount received $: 0.95
You will need....
0 $50 bill(s),
0 $20 bill(s),
0 $10 bill(s),
0 $5 bill(s),
0 $1 bill(s),
1 Quarter(s),
0 Dime(s),
0 Nickle(s) and
4 Penney.
```

Is there anything I am missing here.

Comment: This seems like the perfect time to learn how to use a *debugger* to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values. I also recommend that you split up more complex expressions into smaller expression so it's easier to see intermediate results. That way you can see that even if `x` and `y` are exactly what you entered (which I highly doubt) then perhaps `x - y` might not be.

Comment: As for how to solve your problem: Multiply `moneyCharge` and `moneyGiven` with `100`, and pass them as `int` values to `calculateChange`.

Comment: On another couple of (unrelated) notes: Why division with `1`? That's not really needed, and the compiler will most likely not do it anyway. Also you don't need to pass the `x` and `y` arguments by reference, pass them by value.

Comment: @Some programmer dude
It does solve the problem. Thank you for making good points on "division by 1", it does make sense. Why don't we need to pass it by reference?

Comment: For small types, especially the primitive types like `int` or `double`, it can take more effort to pass by reference than by value. And since you don't modify the argument variables, you don't need to pass by reference.

Answer (score 3):

See the famous paper, "[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)". You simply *can't* use finite-precision representations this way.

Here's the same kind thing in finite-precision decimal. Say we use six digits after the decimal point. Then:

`1/3`'s best representation is `0.333333`
`2/3`'s best representation is `0.666667`
`1.0`'s best representation is `1.000000`

So `2/3 - 1/3` becomes `0.666667 - 0.333333` or `0.333334`
Oops, not exactly 1/3.

You have the same problem here. Just as 1/3 has no exact decimal representation, 30/100 has no exact binary representation.

Again, you *cannot* use finite-precision representations and expect to get exact results.

Comment: Maybe it's worth mentioning what professional accounting software uses instead? Obviously, if you are only interested in whole cents like in the question, you can simply use integer types large enough to hold the number of cents in the largest amount of money you need to represent. In all reality one could even count whole cents correctly in `double`s. But what does one do when one needs fractions?